# Android MediaCodec slower in async-mode than in synchronous mode?

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, android-mediacodec

Again, I have a question as regards Android's MediaCodec class.

I have successfully managed to decode raw h264 content and display the result in two TextureViews. 
The h264 stream comes from a server that is running an openGL scene.

The scene has a camera and hence is responsive to user input.

To further reduce the latency between an input on the server and the actual result on the smartphone, I was thinking about using MediaCodec in its async mode.

Here is how i set up both variants: synchronous and asynchronous:

**Async:**

```
//decoderCodec is "video/avc"
MediaFormat fmt = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(decoderCodec, 1280,720);
codec.setCallback(new MediaCodec.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec codec, int index) {
        byte[] frameData;
        try {
            frameData = frameQueue.take(); //this call is blocking
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }

        ByteBuffer inputData = codec.getInputBuffer(index);
        inputData.clear();
        inputData.put(frameData);

        codec.queueInputBuffer(index, 0, frameData.length, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOutputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec codec, int index, MediaCodec.BufferInfo info) {
        codec.releaseOutputBuffer(index, true);
    }

     //The two other methods are left blank at the moment.

});


codec.configure(fmt, surface, null, 0);
codec.start();
```

**Sync:** (is setup like Async except the `codec.setCallback(...)` part. The class which both variants reside in is a subclass of `Runnable`.

```
public void run() {

    while(!Thread.interrupted())
    {
        if(!IS_ASYNC) {
            byte[] frameData;
            try {
                frameData = frameQueue.take(); //this call is blocking
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }

            int inIndex = codec.dequeueInputBuffer(BUFFER_TIMEOUT);

            if (inIndex >= 0) {
                ByteBuffer input = codec.getInputBuffer(inIndex);
                input.clear();
                input.put(frameData);
                codec.queueInputBuffer(inIndex, 0, frameData.length, 0, 0);
            }

            MediaCodec.BufferInfo bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            int outIndex = codec.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, BUFFER_TIMEOUT);

            if(outIndex >= 0)
                codec.releaseOutputBuffer(outIndex, true);
        }
        else sleep(3000); //Just for testing, if we are in Async, this thread has nothing to do actually...
    }
}
```

Both approaches work, but I'm observing that the videos played in synchronous-mode are much smoother and the latency is also lower.

I came up with the idea of using the async mode because `frameQueue` is a `LinkedBlockingDeque` and I reasoned that should the synchronous decoder wait too long for new frame data to arrive, decoded output may already be available but would not be displayed because of the blocking nature of the queue. On the other hand, I don't want to do something like `busy wait` and poll the queue, the inputBuffers and outputBuffers all the time.

So I tried the AsyncMode using the Callbacks, but the result I get is even worse than in synchronous mode.

The question I have for you guys now is this:

Why? Did I misuse the async mode? or is it something else?

Thanks for any feedback!

Christoph

**Edit:**
The following is the updated code. I am only listing the updated parts. So as 
@mstorsjo pointed out correctly, the culprit was me waiting for more frame data in `onInputBufferAvailable()`. The updated version feeds another BlockingQueue with the available buffer indices. In an additional Thread we are waiting for new frame data AND a new buffer index to queue the frame data for decoding.

```
public class DisplayThread implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<Integer> freeInputBuffers;
    //skipped the uninteresting parts.

    private void initCodec(String decoderCodec) {       
        //skipped the uninteresting parts.
        codec.setCallback(new MediaCodec.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onInputBufferAvailable(MediaCodec codec, int index) {
                freeInputBuffers.add(index);
            }

            //Dont care about the rest of the Callbacks for this demo...
        }
    }   

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!Thread.interrupted())
        {

            byte [] frameData;
            int inputIndex;

            try {
                frameData = frameQueue.take();
                //this was, indeed the culprit. We can wait in an additional thread for an buffer index to 
                // become free AND to get new frameData. When waiting in the callback, we will slow down 
                // the decoder.
                inputIndex = freeInputBuffers.take();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }

            ByteBuffer inputData = codec.getInputBuffer(inputIndex);
            inputData.clear();
            inputData.put(frameData);
            codec.queueInputBuffer(inputIndex, 0, frameData.length, 0, 0);      
        }

        codec.stop();
        codec.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I was ending up with ANR because of this and I was not able to get my head around it... this solved it like magic!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would not be surprised if the blocking call in `onInputBufferAvailable` is the culprit. It feels probable that both `onInputBufferAvailable` and `onOutputBufferAvailable` are called within the same thread, and if you block in one, you stop the other one from running.

I would suggest changing it so that you in `onInputBufferAvailable` just push the buffer index onto some queue, and signal a different thread that there's another buffer available now, then having this second thread wait for buffers from the queue, and do a blocking fetch of input data there.

Comment: You were right. It looks like they are called from the same thread. I will update my question with the working code.

Comment: Please don't update the original question with the new fixed code - to anybody reading the question later (which SO is all about!), it will make absolutely no sense at all, reading the question with the fixed code. If you want to share the fixed code, add it e.g. as a separate section at the end of the question, clearly marked as an edit, with comments saying that this is the fixed version.

Comment: @Christoph Is your fixed code work? did you shared it in some place?

Comment: @Christoph I have the same question. Did you share fixed code somewhere?